# How is possible, using ` >` symbol, you can create a file

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

How is possible, using greater than `>` symbol, you can create a file.
.....In Linux.....

Answer (score 1):

#### Using greater than `>` symbol, create a file

The `>` symbol is used to redirect the output of a command:

> Redirect command output (stdout) into a file
>
> ```
> command > filename
> ```
>
> Redirect error output (stderr) to a file
>
> ```
> command 2> filename
> ```

Source [How-To: Redirection and Process Substitution - Linux - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-redirection.html)

Example:

```
ls > filelist
```

Comment: I would have thought that you of all people would close this in an instant as "not clear enough" or "not focussed enough".

Comment: @user1686 The question is very clear. Just because it is a basic question doesn't mean it should be closed.

Comment: And yet I could say the same about quite a few questions that I thought were very clear and wanted to answer, but found closed...

Comment: @user1686 Well you know the procedure - vote to repoen (with optional edits to the questions)